# Microservice architecture with strong binding to external API

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design

Lets say I have multiple domain services for book, review and customer with a database each and a BFF as proxy/mediator for the client. The BFF brings all data together and communicates with non-domain-services. There is also an external API where some data is fetched from or sent to:

[image]

I am facing some issues here:

1. isolation: The book model is distributed over several services which also implies a lot of request/response mapping. Ergo: If the book domain model changes I have to change a lot of stuff, although, according domain modelling or microservices should rather prevent developers from adjusting multiple services/interfaces.
2. external dependencies: Unfortunately, in the real life scenario it is even worse, because the book service is implicitly highly coupled to the external API, meaning that, if the book model of the external API changes, the book service will probably change too.
3. validation: AFAIK validation should belong to the domain service. In the real life scenario however, I have to access author, customer and book at once, in order to do business validation.

Can you give me some direction how to deal with these issues?

Comment: As far as Problem 1 goes: You could put your Models in a Package (NuGet, npm module, whatever) which you then include in your services. This way, when you change your model you'll have to release a new version of the package and update that in all services.  There's no way that you can only touch one service for this kind of thing, but this way you're at least limiting the amount of changes required to a bare minimum.

Comment: yea we thought about that too, but found a lot of articles in the net saying you should never do that (due to the core principle of isolation and stuff)

Comment: I am agreeing with @Mushroomator. For some breaking changes you can never avoid to change in multiple services but every time if you make change in bookservice impelemtation or some internal business logic change and you have to change other service then it is not good. Microservices surely focus on decoupling and that you can archieve by keeping data required by other service from book service to local to that service. if you change some schema or public contract of book service you have to maintain version and other service needs to comply with that.

Comment: but does that really solve the problem anyway? A model change would mean at least updating the package in all consuming services and probably adjust the mapping